# How to display gender as text instead of checkbox bool in View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I display text Male or Female of gender which is of type bool in table of a view in MVC. Currently, when I added new column Empgender for a DB First approach I'm getting checkboxes for gender column. How can I format this with text. I tried with ternary operator over the column but its not working.
My Model :

```
    public partial class EmployeeInfo
    {
        public int Empid { get; set; }
        public string Empname { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Empsalary { get; set; }
        public bool Empgender { get; set; }
    }
```

My view for displaying the records :

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empsalary)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empgender)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empsalary)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  item.Empgender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Empid }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Empid }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Empid })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My current result :
[image: Observe checkboxes in gender column]

Comment: You can start by changing the data type of your property, inside the `EmployeeInfo` class. Just turn that into a string instead: `public string Empgender { get; set; }`. Check what happens. For DB First, you might want to adjust the database column first, then re-scaffold so that the model class is in sync with the DB.

Comment: `public bool Empgender`??? Does this mean the employee either has a gender or does not have a gender?

Comment: @MetroSmurf No, If the bit value is 0 then Female. If the bit value is 1 then Male, Like wise.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu When I changed the type to string facing exception "'The type 'Edm.Boolean' of the member 'Empgender' in the conceptual side type 'CompanyModel.EmployeeInfo' does not match with the type 'System.String' of the member 'Empgender' on the object side type 'WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeInfo'.'
"

Comment: That's why I mentioned the re-scaffolding part. You need to change the data type in the _database first_, then re-scaffold everything so that the `EmployeeInfo` model gets regenerated and everything is compatible with each other. Turn the column to `VARCHAR` instead of `BIT`.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Is there any way without disturbing the database end ?

Comment: Imagine that you manage to show an input instead of a checkbox. How are you going to save the text in your DB using a column of type BIT that only allows either 1 or 0?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu He doesn't need to record it as a string, to display a string output, bit is fine if that's the limit/range of data he's dealing with.

Otherwise he could switch it to int and use a dropdown, or just increase the radiobutton options in the create/edit page>

The only reason to use a string field would be if the input is expected to not be pre-defined.

Comment: I'm curious why Md Farid answer was marked as correct and not mine, since I provided an answer first and with additional options before MD Farid posted what looks like a copy altered slightly?

I even amended my answer first based off your response, so is there something I'm missing or is it just that Md Farid prompted you that got you to mark his answer as correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How can I display text Male or Female of gender which is of type bool
> in table of a view in MVC. Currently, when I added new column
> Empgender for a DB First approach I'm getting checkboxes for gender
> column. How can I format this with text.

Actually, it can simply be resolved by using if conditional within your foreeach loop. Apart from this, a alternative way can also meet your expected output.  I have tried with your snippet and both scenarios working as expected. You can refer to below sample:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {

            var listEmployee = new List<EmployeeInfo>()
            {
                new EmployeeInfo() { Empid=1,Empname="Dev", Empsalary=95000, Empgender = true },
                new EmployeeInfo() { Empid=2,Empname="Maria", Empsalary=75000, Empgender = false },
                new EmployeeInfo() { Empid=3,Empname="Tim", Empsalary=55000, Empgender = true }

            };
            return View(listEmployee);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Model.EmployeeInfo>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Employee List</h2>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empid)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empname)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empsalary)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empgender)
            </th>
            <th>
                Employees Details
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empid)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empsalary)
                </td>

                @if (item.Empgender)
                {
                    <td>Female</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td> Male </td>
                }

                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Details" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@item.Empid">Details</a> |  <a asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-success" asp-route-id="@item.Empid">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternative Way:

As [displayFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0) tag helper requires IEnumerable so you cannot pass ternary operator directly which would cause runtime exception. Instead you can call it within a variable inside foreeach loop and then pass the value in [@Html.DisplayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.displayname?view=aspnetcore-7.0) tag helper that will also meet your requirement.

Here is the example:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            var gender = @item.Empgender ? "Male" : "Female";

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayName(gender)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** [Please refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), in order to learn more about [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and it's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest inline code would be,

```
<td>
    @(item.Empgender ? "Male" : "Female")
</td>
```

OR

```
<td>
    @(item.Empgender == true ? "Male" : "Female")
</td>
```

Or you could create a display template like, (new "Gender.cshtml" in shared views folder)

```
@model System.Boolean?

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    if (Model.Value)
    {
        <text>Male</text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>Female</text>
    }
}
else
{
    <text>Female</text>
}
```

Or for non-null

```
@model System.Boolean
    
            if (Model.Value) // or if (Model.Value == true)
            {
                <text>Male</text>
            }
            else
            {
                <text>Female</text>
            }
```

Then on the view,

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  item.Empgender, "Gender")
```

Pick any and hope it helps.

Comment: My gender column in database is bit which takes only 0 or 1. So while using ternary it is not working, its throwing exception.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy Hmm I would have thought it should still work but if not try being more explicit @(item.Empgender == true ? "Male" : "Female") or if (Model.Value == true)